# Is it possible to show that gravity emerges from cosmic expansion?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, gravity, time, space-expansion, unitarity

In this paper: https://arxiv.org/abs/2201.11658 the authors discard unitarity in favor of isometry for the time evolution of quantum systems. In this alteration, they are able to show how time is a quantum error correcting code.

Furthermore, since the motivation toward isometry is also directly linked to the expansion of space, it is clear that in this framework, this expansion is responsible for the creation of new information which is isometrically mapped to information in the past. Since quantum error correction is a scheme whereby a small message is redundantly encoded inside a bigger system, the expansion of space becomes a mechanism for the creation of quantum information that encodes the flow of time.

So, if you have two connected regions of space, each expanding at different rates, does curvature not emerge? Does an observer traveling from one region to the other along a geodesic not experience an apparently curved path? Therefore, is it possible that spacetime curvature may arise from the regional differences in the rate of expansion? Since energy densities are known to cause spacetime curvature, I am wondering if the expansion of the universe is a default state from which energy densities necessarily depart in their expansion?

Are energy densities regions of spacetime that cannot expand at the same background rate as empty space and, therefore, do not produce as much information change as empty space does in its expansion?

More speculatively, since expansion itself requires energy, do energy densities consume, convert, or otherwise reduce nearby available dark energy at a rate proportional to their energy content, thereby leading to a reduction in the energy available for expansion and a reduction in the local expansion rate? More speculatively still, does a reduction in the local dark energy available for expansion correspond to the rotation of a 4-velocity out of the time dimension?

Comment: Forget about time and expansion.  Think about this: energy density and its  forms.